# Max amount of memory per java process in 64bit Windows10?

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, jvm, jvm-arguments

I am using 64bit windows10 Operating System with 8GB Ram. My eclipse.ini file is given below:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.
-XX:MaxPermSize
-Xms4000m
-Xmx8000m
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
-Xms4000m
-Xmx8000m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin\javaw.exe
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms4000m
-Xmx8000m
```

I am simply trying to insert 100000 values in Binary Search Tree. When I try to enter 10000 values in BST my code works fine but when I try to insert 100000 values in BST I am facing JVM heap size issue. I have also done following steps
- Go to Run Configurations
- Go to Arguments
- In VM Argument Section 
- I have added -Xms4000m -Xmx8000m

My Code is as follows:

```
public class BinarySearchTree<AnyType extends Comparable<? super AnyType>>
{
 /**
  * Construct the tree.
  */
 public BinarySearchTree( )
 {
     root = null;
 }

 /**
  * Insert into the tree; duplicates are ignored.
  * @param x the item to insert.
  */
 public void insert( AnyType x )
 {
     root = insert( x, root );
 }

 /**
  * Remove from the tree. Nothing is done if x is not found.
  * @param x the item to remove.
  */
 public void remove( AnyType x )
 {
     root = remove( x, root );
 }

 /**
  * Find the smallest item in the tree.
  * @return smallest item or null if empty.
  */
 public AnyType findMin( )
 {
     if( isEmpty( ) )
         return null;
     return findMin( root ).element;
 }

 /**
  * Find the largest item in the tree.
  * @return the largest item of null if empty.
  */
 public AnyType findMax( )
 {
     if( isEmpty( ) )
         return null;
     return findMax( root ).element;
 }

 /**
  * Find an item in the tree.
  * @param x the item to search for.
  * @return true if not found.
  */
 public boolean contains( AnyType x )
 {
     return contains( x, root );
 }

 /**
  * Make the tree logically empty.
  */
 public void makeEmpty( )
 {
     root = null;
 }

 /**
  * Test if the tree is logically empty.
  * @return true if empty, false otherwise.
  */
 public boolean isEmpty( )
 {
     return root == null;
 }

 /**
  * Print the tree contents in sorted order.
  */
 public void printTree( )
 {
     if( isEmpty( ) )
         System.out.println( "Empty tree" );
     else
         printTree( root );
 }

 /**
  * Internal method to insert into a subtree.
  * @param x the item to insert.
  * @param t the node that roots the subtree.
  * @return the new root of the subtree.
*/
 private BinaryNode<AnyType> insert( AnyType x, BinaryNode<AnyType> t )
 {
     if( t == null )
         return new BinaryNode<>( x, null, null );

     int compareResult = x.compareTo( t.element );

     if( compareResult < 0 )
         t.left = insert( x, t.left );
     else if( compareResult > 0 )
         t.right = insert( x, t.right );
     else
         ;  // Duplicate; do nothing
     return t;
 }

 /**
  * Non recursive method, created by LR - 29-092014

 private BinaryNode<AnyType> insert( AnyType x, BinaryNode<AnyType> t )
 {
     if( t == null )
         return new BinaryNode<>( x, null, null );

     while (t != null) {     
         int compareResult = x.compareTo( t.element );

         if( compareResult < 0 )
             t = t.left;
         else if( compareResult > 0 )
             t = t.right;
         else
             ;  // Duplicate; do nothing
     }
         return t;
 }*/

 /**
  * Internal method to remove from a subtree.
  * @param x the item to remove.
  * @param t the node that roots the subtree.
  * @return the new root of the subtree.
  */
 private BinaryNode<AnyType> remove( AnyType x, BinaryNode<AnyType> t )
 {
     if( t == null )
         return t;   // Item not found; do nothing

     int compareResult = x.compareTo( t.element );

     if( compareResult < 0 )
         t.left = remove( x, t.left );
     else if( compareResult > 0 )
         t.right = remove( x, t.right );
     else if( t.left != null && t.right != null ) // Two children
     {
         t.element = findMin( t.right ).element;
         t.right = remove( t.element, t.right );
     }
     else
         t = ( t.left != null ) ? t.left : t.right;
     return t;
 }

 /**
  * Internal method to find the smallest item in a subtree.
  * @param t the node that roots the subtree.
  * @return node containing the smallest item.
  */
 private BinaryNode<AnyType> findMin( BinaryNode<AnyType> t )
 {
     if( t == null )
         return null;
     else if( t.left == null )
         return t;
     return findMin( t.left );
 }

 /**
  * Internal method to find the largest item in a subtree.
  * @param t the node that roots the subtree.
  * @return node containing the largest item.
  */
 private BinaryNode<AnyType> findMax( BinaryNode<AnyType> t )
 {
     if( t != null )
         while( t.right != null )
             t = t.right;

     return t;
 }

 /**
  * Internal method to find an item in a subtree.
  * @param x is item to search for.
  * @param t the node that roots the subtree.
  * @return node containing the matched item.
  */
 private boolean contains( AnyType x, BinaryNode<AnyType> t )
 {
     if( t == null )
         return false;

     int compareResult = x.compareTo( t.element );

     if( compareResult < 0 )
         return contains( x, t.left );
     else if( compareResult > 0 )
         return contains( x, t.right );
     else
         return true;    // Match
 }

 /**
  * Internal method to print a subtree in sorted order.
  * @param t the node that roots the subtree.
  */
 private void printTree( BinaryNode<AnyType> t )
 {
     if( t != null )
     {
         printTree( t.left );
         System.out.println( t.element );
         printTree( t.right );
     }
 }

 /**
  * Internal method to compute height of a subtree.
  * @param t the node that roots the subtree.
  */
 private int height( BinaryNode<AnyType> t )
 {
     if( t == null )
         return -1;
     else
         return 1 + Math.max( height( t.left ), height( t.right ) );    
 }

 // Basic node stored in unbalanced binary search trees
 private static class BinaryNode<AnyType>
 {
         // Constructors
     BinaryNode( AnyType theElement )
     {
         this( theElement, null, null );
     }

     BinaryNode( AnyType theElement, BinaryNode<AnyType> lt, BinaryNode<AnyType> rt )
     {
         element  = theElement;
         left     = lt;
         right    = rt;
     }

     AnyType element;            // The data in the node
     BinaryNode<AnyType> left;   // Left child
     BinaryNode<AnyType> right;  // Right child
 }


   /** The tree root. */
 private BinaryNode<AnyType> root;


 }
```

And Here is my main()

```
public static void main( String [ ] args )
 {
     BinarySearchTree<Integer> t = new BinarySearchTree<>( );
     final int NUMS = 100000;  // must be even
     for( int i = 1; i <= NUMS; i++)
     {
         t.insert( i );
     }

}
```

and I am getting following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

In following method and specifically at the bold line

```
private BinaryNode<AnyType> insert( AnyType x, BinaryNode<AnyType> t )
 {
     if( t == null )
         return new BinaryNode<>( x, null, null );

     int compareResult = x.compareTo( t.element );

     if( compareResult < 0 )
         t.left = insert( x, t.left );
     else if( compareResult > 0 )
         **t.right = insert( x, t.right );**
     else
         ;  // Duplicate; do nothing
     return t;
 }
```

But unfortunately I am getting same error. Somebody please let me know whats wrong with the code, configuration or eclipse.ini file.

Comment: Your default heap size is 2 GB (1/4 of memory) and if you are using 20 KB per value that is a lot for a simple test. I would change your test or fix your code so it doesn't use so much memory before attempting to increase the maximum by 10x as you don't have that much.

Comment: Do I need to change my eclipse.ini file and also Arguments to -Xms1024 -Xmx2056 ?

Comment: the more memory you give eclipse the less memory you have to run programs. I would be tempted to give eclipse only 1 GB given you only have 8 GB and give your programs more memory by configuring your programs not the startup of eclipse. In this case however I would fix your code first. You should be able to create a tree set with 1 million entries easily.

Answer (score 3):

`StackOverflowError` means you have method recursion which is too deep.  It indicates you either need for deep recursion such as 10k+ depth, or you have a bug.

Running out of heap with an `OutOfMemoryError` is when you might consider fixing your heap size, or fixing your program to use less heap.

In this case your depth should be around O(log2(n)) for a balanced tree, but your tree isn't balanced.

i.e. your tree looks like this

```
1 \
  2 \
    3 \
      4 \
        5 \
          6 \ always more to the right.
```

effectively it has turned into a linked list, and the number of elements in the list is the depth the stack need to go to add one more element.

You can increase the stack depth with `-Xss` on the program (not eclipse) however if your plan is to implement a tree and not a linked list, I suggest you make it a balanced tree (or you avoid using recursion as LinkedList does)